# How to make this CFG conflict free?

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar, automata

So I have the following grammar, symbols (a, b, c, d, !):

```
S → N!
N → aNd | aMd | aNdN | aMdN
M → bM | cM | b | c
```

Essentially 'a' and 'd' are brackets and in between have to contain one or more 'b' and/or 'c'. Can have multiple brackets as long as they still contain one or more 'b' and/or 'c'. Must end with !.

So this grammar works but I am struggling to make it conflict-free. The conflicts are with both non terminals N and M, where you can both shift and reduce the same character. I have tried to work around by introducing epsilons and new non-terminals but always have something get in the way.

> Can reduce 'd' and shift 'd' in non terminal N, also shift/reduce 'b'
> and 'c' in non terminal M.

Examples of strings derived from the grammar:

```
abccdaaccdd!
aaabddd!
aabddaccd!
aabbbddabccbcd!
aacbcdacbdd!
acbbccd!
```

I assume my grammar is unambiguous as I don't see anything wrong with it?

How can I make this conflict free?

Thanks!

Comment: What makes you think that has conflicts? Bison certainly doesn't report any.

Comment: Isn't there a conflict for e.g. 'bM' and 'b', as 'b' will reduce whereas 'bM' will shift.

I could be confused but the above part was solved with the comment from Sara.

Comment: only if you're using an LR(0) parser, and if you are you should have mentioned that in the question. The reduction `M->b` is only possible if the lookahead is `d` (which is the only thing in `FOLLOW(M)`) and `d` cannot be shifted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to swap bM in the rule to the Mb?

Comment: Oh I see! Yes that would prevent conflict changing them both to Mb and Mc. Now I'll try thinking of something similar for the ones in N.

Thanks!